# How can I apply Proptypes properly on my React component?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import ClearIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';

const InputSearch = ({ onClearSearch, onSearch, ...searchProps }) => {
    const { id, value } = searchProps;

    const onClear = (event) => {
         onClearSearch(event, id);
    };

     return (
        <TextField
            id={id}
            name={id}
            onChange={onSearch}
            value={value}
            InputProps={{
                endAdornment: value && (
                    <IconButton
                        className={classes.searchIcon}
                        onClick={onClear}
                    > 
                        <ClearIcon fontSize={'small'} color={'primary'} />
                    </IconButton>
                ),
             }}
        />
    );
};

InputSearch.propTypes = {
    onClearSearch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default InputSearch;
```

As you can see, I'm trying to apply a required validation using `propTypes`. But then, when I try to use the component without the `onClearSearch` function, no error is being shown:

```
<InputSearch
     value={searchBy}
     onSearch={handleSearch}
     />
```

So what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right... you can open developer tool of chrome by pressing F12 -> go to **Console** and you can see prop type error

for more detail you can see
https://blog.logrocket.com/validating-react-component-props-with-prop-types-ef14b29963fc/

If you want your project give prop-type error in terminal then you have to setup eslint in your project.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that it doesn't appear on developer tools.

Comment: share your code in online editor.. it's giving error in my end